# AntiAliasing routine for downsizing

Tags: c++, antialiasing

i'm trying to implement a custom anti-aliasing routine by summing nearest pixels for downsizing an image.

I tried to sum and mean up to 3 pixels-wide but the result is not good, it's as much antialised (*edit* i mean *aliased*) as before.

here is the code i used:

```
h is height
w is width
buf is a buffer containing the values.
out is the output buffer

for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {
        int n = 3;
        int x1 = x - n;
        int x2 = x + n;

        if (x1 < 0) x1 = 0;
        if (x2 > w -1) x2 = w - 1;

        int y1 = y - n; 
        int y2 = y + n;

        if (y1 < 0) y1 = 0;
        if (y2 > h - 1) y2 = h - 1;

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = x1; i <= x2; i++)
            for (int j = y1; j <= y2; j++)
                 sum += buf[i][j];

        sum = sum / double((x2 - x1 +1) * (y2 - y1 +1));
        out[x][y] = sum;
    }
```

What quick routine could i use to do a simple basic anti-aliasing?

Comment: edge detection + blur maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by "as before"? What did you try exactly before?

Comment: as before as in : before applying the effect. But i read around some texts and i think i simply didn't do the mean of enough pixels as i resample images as big as 4000x4096 to 950x256 what do you think?

Comment: If you are scaling down to ratio `r` an image, you probably want to average up `r` pixels. So if scaling down 3 times, 3 pixels wide is the maximum, since there will be 3 times less pixels in the target image. Above that limit, you are doing a bluring algorithm.

Comment: You could experiment on how far apart should these pixels be. I _guess_ the stock algorithm uses the directly surrounding ones. You could also give a higher weight to the central pixel.

Comment: However I am not very knowledgeable on this topic, I just rely on my common sense here. Hopefully someone with a better understanding will provide insight.

Comment: Do you have a sample image that you're using as a test case?

Comment: @didierc:  Image scaling is a large and rich field.  The type of image you're scaling makes a big difference in the type of algorithm you want to apply.  For continuous tone images, you can treat it as a resampling problem, and use an appropriate low-pass filter.  (Even then, you get into the wonderful world of filter design.)  If you're trying to preserve features and edges, it gets complicated; nonlinear approaches are common.  For most things, though, a simple Gaussian blur whose radius is a little wider than the area covered by a target pixel does well.  That's why I asked for a test case.

Comment: @Joe Z thanks for clarifying things for me: I was not disputing your input, but merely sharing what I found so far by looking up the topic.